# Error using meteor ground db package for client persistence in ionic2 project

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using meteors/mongo with my ionic2/angular2 app. In my app, I need the client data to persist offline. I came across the meteor package ground db https://atmospherejs.com/ground/db for client side persistence but am having errors in creating the ground collection in client.

I ground the collections in collections.ts which is common to both client and server. My code is

```
export const Messages = new MongoObservable.Collection("messages");
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Ground.Collection(Messages);
    Ground.Collection(Meteor.users);
}
```

In client I am getting the error

```
"First argument to new Mongo.Collection must be a string or null
    at v (polyfills.js:3)
    at new Mongo.Collection (meteor-client.js:32177)
    at Object.groundCollection [as Collection]"
```

my ground:db version is 0.3.15 and meteor version is 1.4.4.1. I would appreciate any help with this issue.

Comment: The docs state that you need to create an offline-only collection and sync it using a cursor. Have you read the readme file?

Comment: @MasterAM what happens is that `ground:db` has not been updated for a while. The repo default branch is actually the [development one](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db/tree/grounddb-caching-2016), whereas the [`master`](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db/tree/master) branch still reflects the last published version (i.e. [`0.3.15`](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db/tree/aa5b432fc31045b61d4573ced3b64a31aa9f25d6)). Hence the mismatch between the GitHub and Atmosphere README's.

Comment: @ghybs, I see, my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to feed the "raw" Meteor Mongo Collection to `Ground.Collection`, instead of the angular2-meteor wrapped one:

```ts
const Messages = new MongoObservable.Collection("messages");

Ground.Collection(Messages.collection);
```

- `Messages` is the angular2-meteor collection with RxJS observables wrapper.
- `Messages.collection` is the [underlying](https://angular-meteor.com/api/meteor-rxjs/latest/ObservableCollection#Collection+collection) Meteor Mongo Collection (i.e. what you would have gotten if directly executing `new Mongo.Collection("messages")` )

Comment: The initial error was resolved after i upgraded the ground db to v2.0.0-rc.7. But now I get a white screen after splash component in device. I am adding the following code in collection.ts which is common to both client and server "export const Messages = new MongoObservable.Collection("messages");
 

if(Meteor.isClient){
Ground.Collection(Messages);
Ground.Collection(Meteor.users)

}". The error I am getting on device is - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at exports.default (main.js:141750)
    at Object.GroundCollection [as Collection] (main.js:190326)"